# VB.Net Imagelist Listview from URL

Tags: vb.net, image, load, imagelist

I have a Website displaying multiple jpg Images and I want to load them from URl and display them in my Imagelist.

I was able to do that with Images on my SSD Using the following code:

```
Dim count as integer = 0
Dim imgs as ImageList = New ImageList()
imgs.ImageSize = New Size(75, 75)

Dim files as String()
files = Directory.GetFiles("C:/image/folger")

ListView.SmallImageList = imgs  

For each x in files
   imgs.Images.Add(Image.FromFile(f))
   ListView.Items.Add("Image Number: " & count, count)
Next
```

Now I want to achieve the same thing but from an URL without downloading the files to my driver first. I got it 50% done using the following code:

```
    //Loading the Image from URL into Memory as Bitmap fuirst
    Dim tClient As WebClient = New WebClient
    Dim tImage As Bitmap = Bitmap.FromStream(New MemoryStream(tClient.DownloadData("https://url.to.image/1.jpg"))) 

    //Applying the Bitmap from Memory into the ImageList
    Dim imgs As ImageList = New ImageList()
    imgs.ImageSize = New Size(50, 50)
    imgs.Images.Add(tImage)

    ListView1.SmallImageList = imgs
    ListView1.Items.Add("Image " & vbCrLf & count.ToString, count)
```

This works great but as you can see the "Loop - For Each" is missing. I don't know how to request or collect each image on the website. As all images are "x.jpg" and x is always and only a number i thought about searching trough the websites sourcecode for each image until there is no image left. Would be great if someone could help me out with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download the photos until you get an http error 404 , meaning that the address is not existing .

```
Dim pictIndx As Integer = 0
Dim tClient As WebClient = New WebClient
Dim imgs As ImageList = New ImageList()

Try
   While True
       'Download until you get 404
       pictIndx += 1
       Dim tImage As Bitmap = Bitmap.FromStream(New MemoryStream(tClient.DownloadData("https://url.to.image/" & pictIndx & ".jpg"))) 
       'Download the image
       imgs.ImageSize = New Size(50, 50)
       imgs.Images.Add(tImage)
       'Add the image to the ListView
       ListView1.SmallImageList = imgs
       ListView1.Items.Add("Image " & vbCrLf & count.ToString, count)

   End While
Catch ex as Exception
 'You downloaded all the photos
End Try
```

Let me know if this doesn't work